# python binary search tree size

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, nodes, counting

im trying to implement a binary search tree and im having trouble with my `size()` method, which counts the number of nodes in the tree.

```
class BSTNode:
def __init__(self, item):

    self._element = item
    self._leftchild = None
    self._rightchild = None
    self._parent = None
```

this is what my size funtion looks like:

```
def size(self):

    size = 0
    if self != None:
        size += 1
        if self._leftchild != None:
            size += 1 + self._leftchild.size()
        if self._rightchild != None:
            size += 1 + self._rightchild.size()
    return size
```

it overcounts the number of nodes that are actually in the tree and i dont know why, maybe because its recursive but im not  sure.

Comment: By saying `size`, you mean the number of nodes in the tree? If you could also provide with a sample case of input and output, it would help a lot.

Comment: yeah sorry if that wasnt clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
size += 1 + self._leftchild.size()
```

With

```
size += self._leftchild.size()
```

That extra 1 is the reason for overcounting. And similarly for right child.

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the nodes twice. You should only be counting each node once.

```
def size(self):

    size = 0
    if self != None:
        size += 1
        if self._leftchild != None:
            size += self._leftchild.size()
        if self._rightchild != None:
            size += self._rightchild.size()
    return size
```